# a fair amount of/a good deal of

Tags: meaning, expressions

Does 'a fair amount of' mean the same as 'a good deal of' and 'a great deal of'?

I think the two latter idioms mean 'a lot of', but 'a fair amount of' is somewhat less than that. Maybe it is just my impression, or maybe different people use the expressions in slightly different ways...

Many thanks

Comment: A fair amount could be one which is merely _not negligible_, whereas a great deal is always _a lot_.